# Related questions

Tags: discussion, answers

I'm new to this site.  Often I have a question related to an earlier one, or one needing clarification.  I'd like to add that to the existing thread rather than starting a new one, but a window pops up reminding me to not do that, but rather post answers.  Should a new thread be started for every question?  If not, then should that popup be revised?

Comment: Each SE site has a separate meta site for questions like this; meta.drupal.stackexchage.com is the one for Drupal Answers. I've voted to move your question to that site, it might be an idea to flag it yourself and ask a moderator to move it :)

Comment: I am not sure to which popup you are referring. I have never seen a popup suggesting to write an answer instead of something else.

Comment: I originally posted to the non-meta SE site.  If you click on the box labelled Your Answer, a reminder message rises up from it telling you that it should be an answer and not another question.  @Clive - Thanks.  I'm not sure what a meta site is for.  I'm guessing it's for questions about asking questions or about how to use the main question site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to ask a clarification for a question, or an answer posted from somebody else, you should write a comment, but your reputation allows you to write a comment for:

- Your own answers
- Your own questions
- Any of the answers given to your questions

If you want to ask a clarification for a question asked from other users (or any answer given for questions asked from other users), you need to wait your reputation is at least 50.

Keep in mind that Stack Exchange sites are not forums: There aren't threads, but questions and their answers. Answers are only used for answering the question, not for commenting, or asking any related question for the question itself, or any of the given answers.

Comment: Thanks.  That makes sense, but it's a shame, since the right question was already asked (which is how I came to looking at SE in the first place), yet neither answer was a good solution as far as I can tell, and it seems that the people that were kind enough to post their answers don't even realize that their answers didn't solve the issue.  How do you address this if you can't ask for a clarification or tell them that it doesn't work?  Do you post the same question again?

Comment: If there is a question for which the existing answers don't answer correctly, or with much details, there are just two things you can do: Write an answer yourself, if you know the answer; offer a bounty so that somebody else writes an answer, but that requires at least a reputation of 75.

Comment: I certainly don't know the answer, just that the answers provided don't solve the issue.  Regarding bounties, I don't see an explanation of that in the about nor the FAQ sections.  Where is the system explained?

Comment: [What if I don't get a good answer?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/faq#bounty)